# How to set the fontsize of text in JTextpane using double value in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am trying to build a java Swing application where the user will have an option to set a desired font size of text in jtextpane. I am using "StyleConstants.setFontSize(attr, int);". This works only for integer value, but when user gives double value Eg(8.5), the above command fails as it accepts only integer value and not double value. So how do I resolve this? Is there any command which accepts double value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to `Math.round` the double to an Integer (or `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`) or really accept the 8.5 . Not sure what a font with size 8.5 would be

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response... I would like to have a font size of 8.5 only. It should be similar to the one in MSWord. I mean in MSWord, we can specify even double values(6.5, 8.5) and it works fine in MSWord. I want exactly the same behaviour in my application

Comment: The only way around this short of developing your own font system, would be to cast the double to an int.

Comment: Not sure what the result would be, but create a font with an integer size and the use `Font#deriveFont( float size )` ..,

Comment: But Darren how will it resolve my purpose? casting 8.5 to integer would give a value of 8. But I need to specify the size of 8.5.

Comment: Robin can you please provide a small example of deriveFont as I had tried it earlier but it didn't work. It would be very helpful if you can provide a small example.

Comment: What do you mean with "did not work". Exceptions, or simply no difference between a size of 8 and size of 8.5 (as I am not sure whether java Fonts support non-integer sizes)

Answer (score 1):

You could try via HTML/CSS:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setText("<span style='font-size: 8.5pt'>Hey there!</span>");
```

Comment: I am not sure the HTML editor that Swing uses supports font sizes in `pt` (though have not tried it), I typically use `px`.  Can you confirm it works?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the Swing HTML renderer differentiates between pt and px. I would personally only use pt for print, but since @user1815809 was explicitly asking about 8.5 (i.e. a fraction), px didn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: Hi netzwerg.. sorry for the late response. Correct me if I am wrong but if I follow the above approach then it would override all the contents in the textpane with the new one. What I want is to modify only the selected text and keeping the remaining contents untouched

Comment: My minimal example illustrates how you can format text by surrounding it with a `style` element . Obviously, you shouldn't use the `Hey there!` snippet straight away, but surround your own text/selection.

Answer (score 0):

The following swing components support HTML formatting: buttons, menu items, labels, tool tips and tabbed panes. To use the formatting it is necessary at the beginning of the text to put  tag (closing it at the end is optional.) For example:

```
<html><font size="8.5pt">Two</font>
```